# Match email with a-z and dots or plus

Tags: regex, pcre

I am trying to match emails with gmail domain that have as name the following characters: a-z, plus|dot. So, in the following list of emails:

```
answer.me...charlie@gmail.com
answer.me...charlie@tsunami.org
godfrey+assclown@gmail.com
wisk+as+w+e+rain@gmail.com
atomic+sam@outlook.org
canceee@gmail.com
linkedrebel@gmail.com
nuclearimpact+empoly@gmail.com
clericly.ass@gmail.com
r@gmail.com
```

Should match:

```
answer.me...charlie@gmail.com
godfrey+assclown@gmail.com
wisk+as+w+e+rain@gmail.com
nuclearimpact+empoly@gmail.com
clericly.ass@gmail.com
```

I tried with:

```
^((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[.+]).+)@(g(?:oogle)?mail\.com)$
```

But the dot in the list `[.+]` is matching the dot of the domain name, making match all domain names. If I remove the dot, it matches only emails with plus characters as name. Any solution for that problem?

Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/bKqzan/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may temper all dots with `[^@]`:

```
^(?=[^@]*[a-z])(?=[^@]*[.+])([^@]+)@(g(?:oogle)?mail\.com)$
```

This way all lookahead restrictions are only applied to the part before `@`. A more efficient variation:

```
^(?=[^@a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^@.+]*[.+])([^@]+)@(g(?:oogle)?mail\.com)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bKqzan/3).

**Details**

- `^` - staert of string
- `(?=[^@]*[a-z])` - a positive lookahead that requires a lowercase letter after any 0+ chars other than `@`
- `(?=[^@]*[.+])`  - a positive lookahead that requires a plus or dot after any 0+ chars other than `@`
- `([^@]+)` - Group 1: 1+ chars other than `@`
- `@` - a `@` char
- `(g(?:oogle)?mail\.com)` - Group 2: `g` optionally followed with `oogle` and then `mail.com`
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need lookaheads, I think. You want to match (a) zero or more lowercase letters, followed by (b) at least one dot or plus sign, followed by (c) zero or more lowercase letters, dots, and/or pluses. Correct? So this should work:

`^([a-z]*[.+]+[a-z.+]*)@(g(?:oogle)?mail\.com)$`

(See [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/J8pzZg/2))